# Rendering a gif in Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I am new to C# and axml. I have created a simple page in Monodroid that should contain a `.gif`image. The image has a transparent background. What should display is the following

[image]

Instead it displays as

[image]

The background is not transparent anymore. I am using a ImageView that looks as follow

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

How would I get the background transparent if possible?

Comment: Is it possible to use a PNG instead?

Comment: @Cheesebaron It is, but it includes doing some more photo shop editing

Comment: I would recommend using PNG's as they are a lot better supported. They also allow for better alpha channel handling.